# .replace with matched pattern +1 (integer)

Tags: javascript, replace

I'm trying to update a number within a string

currently I'm using:

```
savedJobsDiv.innerHTML = savedJobsDiv.innerHTML.replace(/.*\(|\)/gi, parseInt('$1')+1);
```

to repalce eberythign inside some () brackets with the matches value +1, but it doesnt quite work, what I get is NAN33NAN, with 33 being the right number, or whatever the maths works out as.

where am I going wrong?

so my start string is:

```
random string here (33)
```

and I want to +1 to the number inside the brackets:

```
random string here (34)
```

Comment: Please post `savedJobsDiv.innerHTML` before the replacement and the desired result.

Comment: If the number is always at the end of the string, do you really need a regex ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$1` will have no value because you have no sub-groups matched in your pattern. `$1` would match to the first group denoted in brackets (you have brackets, but they are matching literal brackets - they are not part of the pattern, i.e. to match a sub-group).

For more computational replacement such as this it's better to feed your match to a callback.

```
"random string here (33)".replace(/(\()([\d\.]+)(?=\))/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
    //$0 == whole match; $1 == first bracket; $2 == number
    return $1+(parseFloat($2)+1);
}); // == "random string here (34)"
```

Using `parseFloat` allows for floats as well as whole numbers, but works with both, so is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var newstr = "random string here (33)".replace(/\((\d+)\)$/,function(cap0,cap1) {
    return '('+(parseFloat(cap1)+1)+')';
});
//newstr = "random string here (34)"
```